# How to control links2 with Python

Tags: python, pexpect

How can I execute links2 to open a web page and locate and click a text link with Python?

Is pexpect able to do it? Any examples are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this. If you want to grab the web link and process the page content, [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) together with an HTML parser ([BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for example) may be just fine.

If you do want to simulate moust clicks, you may want to use [AutoPy](http://github.com/msanders/autopy#readme).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use links2? I don't see how you could benefit from that. It is probably better to approach your problem in a different way, like with [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or maybe even [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).

Please provide a description of your overall problem instead of that specific question

Comment: Links2 is more like a real browser which supports Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

if you want javascript support use selenium rc with whatever language you are comfortable with